# why getPackageArchiveInfo return null

Tags: java, android

I want to use getPackageArchiveInfo to get other apk's resouce,but i get null , i don't know where is error . this is my code.

```
   public void loadSkinAsync(String dexPath, final loadSkinCallBack callback) {
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Resources>() {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.startloadSkin();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Resources doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    if (params.length == 1) {

                        String dexPath_tmp = params[0];
                        File file = new File(dexPath_tmp);
                        PackageManager mPm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        PackageInfo mInfo = mPm.getPackageArchiveInfo(dexPath_tmp, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

                        mPackageName = mInfo.packageName;

                        AssetManager assetManager = AssetManager.class.newInstance();
                        Method addAssetPath = assetManager.getClass().getMethod("addAssetPath", String.class);
                        addAssetPath.invoke(assetManager, dexPath_tmp);

                        Resources superRes = mContext.getResources();
                        Resources skinResource = new Resources(assetManager, superRes.getDisplayMetrics(), superRes.getConfiguration());
                        return skinResource;
                    }
                    return null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }

            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Resources result) {
                mResources = result;

                if (callback != null) {
                    if (mResources != null) {
                        callback.loadSkinSuccess();
                    } else {
                        callback.loadSkinFail();
                    }
                }
            }

        }.execute(dexPath);
    }
```

first i get PackageManager ,then i use it to get PackageInfo ,but PackageInfo is null .

Comment: you still do not provide any of the needed information. which PackageManager class are we talking about? is it one you wrote yourself? what do you pass as variables? have you debugged your code?

Answer (score 0):

You may missed the following permission if you are reading a file which is not in your app directory:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```